# Change layout background dynamically

Tags: android, background, android-layout

I want to change layout background dynimically.

Here is the log from the LogCat:

```
04-10 14:59:55.291: WARN/dalvikvm(263): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-10 14:59:55.309: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-8 exiting due to uncaught exception
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:557)
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:7275)
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7188)
04-10 14:59:55.331: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(263):     at walk.me.Splasher$1.run(Splasher.java:35)

walk.me.Splasher$1.run(Splasher.java:35) is this line:  

layout.setBackgroundResource(temp); What should I do?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **Handler** or run it on the UI thread. A **Handler** can do this task better.

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: But I had this same thread with one image staying for a while on the screen so I now want several images to change and occur in the while loop. Is it because of that I used thread in stead Handler?

Comment: Use handler.postRunnable(wallPaperRunnable, delay) and you'll be done. Read the Handler documentation from http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the user interface from a background thread. See the article [PainlessThreading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html). From the structure of your code, I strongly suggest you use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as described in that article. It allows you to run a background thread that repeatedly triggers actions on the UI thread. Once you learn how to use the AsyncTask class, this kind of thing is easier than feeding individual Runnable objects to a Handler.

Comment: Gives error on the LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.splash); line

Comment: @NikolaMKD - `findViewById` is another method that can only be used on the UI thread. Based on your code, I'd recommend that you subclass AsyncTask (or Thread) with a constructor that takes a LinearLayout argument and that you call `findViewById on the UI thread when you're setting up the AsyncTask or Thread.

Comment: @NikolaMKD - the code you posted in pastebin is overly complex. You don't need to create a separate thread inside `doInBackground`. That method will be called in a background thread as it is and you can call `sleep` there directly without blocking the UI thread.